# Migrating an iTunes Playlist from one computer to another

Tags: itunes, script, migration, playlists

Awhile ago, I moved all of my iTunes music from one computer to another, but I did so without copying the actual iTunes library folder from one to another.  Since then, the libraries have diverged.  Unfortunately, there are several playlists that I'd like to move from one computer to another.  Is there any way built-in to iTunes to do this, provided that the proper songs exist on the target machine?  If not, is there a third-party tool that can cross-reference the exported XML playlist with the songs in the iTunes library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Export the source iTunes library as an XML file (File>Export Library…). This will create a file that holds information about the location, song filenames, and *song rating*!
> 2. Replace the file paths in your XML file with the path that the songs from the source library will be in when you import them. This path may point to your FireWire Drive, a DVD you have burned, or a temporary folder on your hard drive that you have copied your music to. Just to be sure of the new path, copy one of the files from this location to your library, export your destination library, and look at the file path to that song in the resulting XML file. To actually replace the file paths, I did a Find/Change in TextWrangler.
> 3. Set the preferences in iTunes in your source library to “Copy files to iTunes Music folder when adding to library.” This is under “Advanced.”
> 4. Import your library (File>Import).
> 5. Delete redundant files. If you’re like me, you have some duplicate songs in your multiple libraries. This is a tedious task, but I plan to do it over time.

http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/transfer-itunes-library/